# Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am using ajax to do some mathematical calculations. The controller sends the correct response back but the data is not being displayed (when I try to do console.log(data) after success) and instead alerts an error message `- "Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 4".` I have been debugging since yesterday to no success.

Here is the JSON being returned

```
{
  mydata: {
    items: [
      20.68
    ],
    sub_total: 20,
    tax_total: 0.68,
    grand_total: 20.68
  }
}
```

[image]

This is the Ajax function

```
function totalItem() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url("finance/items/totalItem") }}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $('#items input[type=\'text\'],#items input[type=\'hidden\'], #items textarea, #items select'),
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $.each( data.items, function( key, value ) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //$('#item-total-' + key).html(value);
                    $('#item-total-' + key).val(value);
                });
                $('#sub-total').html(data.sub_total);
                $('#tax-total').html(data.tax_total);
                $('#grand-total').html(data.grand_total);
            }
         },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert("Error : "+thrownError);
         }
     });
}
```

My Controller

```
public function totalItem(Request $request)
    {
        //
        //$input_items = request('item');
        $input_items = $request->item;
        $mydata = new \stdClass;
        $sub_total = 0;
        $tax_total = 0;
        //$tax = 0;
        $items = array();

        if ($input_items) {
            foreach ($input_items as $key => $item) {
                //return response()->json($item['tax_id']);
                $item_tax_total = 0;
                $price = isset($item['price']) ? $item['price'] : 0;
                $qty = isset($item['quantity']) ? $item['quantity'] : 0;
                $item_sub_total = ($price * $qty);
                //$item_sub_total = (2 * 2);
                if (isset($item['tax_id'])) {
                    $tax = Tax::find($item['tax_id']);
                    $rate = isset($tax->rate) ? $tax->rate : 0;
                    $item_tax_total = (($price * $qty) / 100) * $rate;
                }

                $sub_total += $item_sub_total;
                $tax_total += $item_tax_total;
                $total = $item_sub_total + $item_tax_total;

                //$items[$key] = money($total, $currency_code, true)->format();
                $items[$key] = $total;

                //return response()->json($tax);
                //return response()->json($sub_total);
            }
        }

        $mydata->items = $items;
        $mydata->sub_total = $sub_total; //money($sub_total, $currency_code, true)->format();
        $mydata->tax_total = $tax_total; //money($tax_total, $currency_code, true)->format();
        $grand_total = $sub_total + $tax_total;
        $mydata->grand_total = $grand_total; //money($grand_total, $currency_code, true)->format();
        return response()->json(['mydata' => $mydata]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the json?

Comment: Analyze the JSON returned by the server with a JSON validator (google suggests https://jsonlint.com/). Common errors are missing `"` or commas. note that just double quotes are valid JSON and all keys have to be wrapped in quotes too. The trouble is there

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have added the JSON being returned

Comment: @ilmirons I have added the JSON being returned

Comment: That is not a [valid JSON](http://json.org/). Missing a couple `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Missing double quotes. The JSON should be

```
{
  "mydata": {
    "items": [
      20.68
    ],
    "sub_total": 20,
    "tax_total": 0.68,
    "grand_total": 20.68
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the json being seen on the browser

Comment: That is not JSON. That is an object. JSON is a string. AJAX function is complaining because the string your server is returning does not have quotes (according to waht you have written below 'Here is the JSON being returned'). You should look at the network panel of chrome tools (or whatever browser you are using) and see exactly what the server is sending.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of that.

Comment: That is already parsed by the browser. I need to see a string (anyway the problem is 99% missing quotes or comma). Edit: Sorry, just noticed there is a "true" in front of your JSON (see picture)

Comment: No. It does not matter. I know whats causing it.

Comment: Whatever is causing it, if it is in the string sent you back by the server just before the first `{` as it appears to be, it is the cause of the error